# Is it possible to filter arrays without filtering inside jsonb in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I was wondering if it is possible to filter array inside jsonb without filtering the whole table or unnesting it?

Say I have a table:

| id | jsnob |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{"names":["anna", "peter", "armin"]}` |
| 2 | `{"names":["anna"]}` |
| 3 | `{"names":["peter"]}` |

I want to have the same table, but so that names are filtered, to only names starting from "a":

| id | jsnob |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{"names":["anna", "armin"]}` |
| 2 | `{"names":["anna"]}` |
| 3 | `{"names":null}` |

I implemented it with unnest ( jsonb_array_elements), and then group by back to json, but it is quite slow. I was wondering if there is a faster way?

Comment: Use a subquery instead of a group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it record by record using a scalar subquery w/o need to flatten the whole table and then re-group. Here is an `update` example.

```sql
update the_table 
set "jsonb" = jsonb_set("jsonb", '{names}',
  (select jsonb_agg(e) from jsonb_array_elements_text("jsonb"->'names') e where e ~* '^a')
);
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vZwqFUEUcaecBmmwcLhhpK/1)

**Note** The above does *not* guarantee that the order of the array elements is retained. To be strict use the scalar subquery below.

```sql
(
 select jsonb_agg(e ORDER BY i) 
 from jsonb_array_elements_text("jsonb"->'names') WITH ORDINALITY t(e, i)
 where e ~* '^a'
)
```

Comment: That works like a charm! Thank you!